# Why does appending a string to a Date invoke toString() rather than valueOf()?

Tags: javascript

Just stumbled upon this today and I couldn't find where this behavior is defined in the spec.

Appending a string to an object in JavaScript (i.e. `new Object() + "whatever"`) typically triggers a call to `valueOf()` on the object, but apparently, Date objects are an exception to this rule: `new Date() + "..."` calls `toString()` on the Date instead.

```js
function test(constructor)
{
    var name = constructor.name || /^\s*function ([\w\$]+)/.exec(constructor.toString())[1];
    var obj = new constructor();
    obj.toString = function () { return name + ' : toString()'; }
    obj.valueOf = function () { return name + ' : valueOf()'; }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV')).textContent = obj + '';
}

test(Array);
test(Boolean);
test(Date);
test(Function);
test(Number);
test(Object);
test(RegExp);
test(String);
```

Question: what is different about Date objects here?

Comment: How have you done this code snippet thing?

Comment: @Ultra: Look at the edit panel for inserting an answer below. There's  a button for it.

Comment: It seems like you could really benefit from a [snippet console](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the [addition operator](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) on an object, and the object is converted [to a primitive](https://es5.github.io/#x9.1), the internal [`[[DefaultValue]]` method](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) of the object is called. The method takes a type hint which determines whether `toString` should be evaluated first or `valueOf`.

If the hint is "String", then `toString` is looked for, before `valueOf`. If "Number" is passed, it's vice versa.

However (emphasis mine):

> When the `[[DefaultValue]]` internal method of *O* is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, **unless *O* is a Date object (see [15.9.6](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.6)), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String**.

This is also noted in the [addition operator section](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1):

> NOTE 1 No hint is provided in the calls to [`ToPrimitive`](https://es5.github.io/#x9.1) in steps 5 and 6. All native ECMAScript objects except Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint String were given. Host objects may handle the absence of a hint in some other manner.